# Git - How do I show file content for each file in the commit?

Tags: git

How can I show file content for each file in the commit?

For example, say the commit has 20 files changed. Right now, I'm using `git show *commit*:*file_path*` 20 times for each file.

Is there a way to get all this information in just one git command?

Comment: Are you looking for the *content of changed files* or the *list of changed files*?

Comment: Content of changed files. I'm already using `git diff --name-only commit` to get a list of changed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just check out that commit, then look at those files (and ignore any other files). Note that you can check out to a different work-tree, e.g., using `git worktree add` (available since Git version 2.5, mostly reliable as of 2.6.x, but best to be on 2.8+ probably):

```
$ git worktree add /tmp/tmpbranch HEAD~3
Preparing /tmp/tmpbranch (identifier tmpbranch)
HEAD is now at ...
$ ... work with files in /tmp/tmpbranch ...
```

You can see what you have with:

```
$ git worktree list
/home/torek/[path]    d22d10a [master]
/tmp/tmpbranch        b6fc8a3 (detached HEAD)
```

and clean up like this:

```
$ rm -rf /tmp/tmpbranch
$ git worktree prune
```

Note that you can place the new work-tree anywhere, but I would put it somewhere out of the current work-area (or even in /tmp like this) just to avoid confusing myself.

(I called this `tmpbranch`, but using `HEAD~3` as the commit-specifier caused it to become detached.  Without that, Git would have checked out the `HEAD` commit under the new branch name `tmpbranch`.  Giving a branch name as the commit-specifier checks out that branch in the new work-tree, unless you add `--detach` to get a detached HEAD.  Using a raw commit hash should get you a detached HEAD every time.)

Comment: Thanks, I was worried I would have to do something like this.

Comment: Well, you can also always just use a shell script loop: `for path in p1 p2 p3 ... pN; do git show $commit:$path > /tmp/dir/$path; done`.  The main drawback to `git show` is that it does not run files through filters (which is also its main plus-side).  I just think a simple temporary work-tree is *easier*.

Answer (score 0):

You could rebase interactively your commits and squash them. Then do git show for that one commit hash. For instance, you could do the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~20
# your terminal will display either nano editor or vim. The format will be as such
# pick *commit_hash* *commit_message*
# pick *commit_hash* *commit_message*
# pick *commit_hash* *commit_message*
# pick *commit_hash* *commit_message*

#change all of your 'pick' to 's' (s means squash). Start from the bottom and go up
#Save your changes on which ever editor you are using. Git will prompt you to name your squash commit
# Then just do git show *commit_hash*
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then you can undo your changes by looking at git reflog

Comment: That's a good idea. I didn't think about it that way. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: let me know if you have any questions

Comment: He has one commit with 20 files, not 20 commits with one file, doesn't he?

Comment: Yea, you're right Vampire. One commit, 20 files. Sorry.